# $A+A' \equiv B+B'$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

If $A$, $A'$, $B$ and $B'$ are linearly ordered sets, and in signature $\{<,=\}$ $A \equiv B$ (elementarily equivalent) and $A'\equiv B'$, is it true that $A+A' \equiv B+B'$? and if it is true why? I'm looking for any help

Comment: That sounds like it should be true. Do you know about the [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game)?

Comment: yes, but I'm not very good at it

Comment: Well, my advice is to try using that game to show that $A+A'\equiv B+B'$.

Comment: Is the order in (say) $A + A'$ given by $a < a'$ if and only if [($a<a'$ and $a, a' \in A$) or $(a \in A$ and $a' \in A')]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so following the hint given by bof in the comments I'm going to use Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé (EF for short) games to provide an answer to the question. As a quick disclaimer, since there are different notations/names given to these sort of constructions I'll just pick one of these once and for all; my choice will be to use the notation and names as given in Marker's *Model Theory* book. For the sake of completeness, let me properly write all the involved notation and definitions.

- We work with the $\{<, =\}$-structures $\mathscr A, \mathscr A', \mathscr B$ and $ \mathscr B'$ such that $\mathscr A \equiv \mathscr B$ and $\mathscr A' \equiv \mathscr B'$. I'll denote the universes of these structures by $A, A', B$ and $B'$, respectively.
- The universe of $\mathscr A + \mathscr A'$ is the disjoint union $A \dot{\cup} A'$ and the interpretation of $<$ in this structure is: $$a<a' \ \ \iff \ \ [(a, a' \in A \text{ and } a<a' \text{ in } A)\ \ \text{or} \ \ (a\in A \text{ and } a' \in A')].$$
- We denote $G_n(\mathscr M, \mathscr N)$ to be the *EF game of length* $n$ *on the* $\{<, =\}$-*structures* $\mathscr M$ *and* $\mathscr N$. Note that $n\geq 1$, i.e. there is no game of length $0$.
- The players of the game are player $I$ and player $II$; player $I$ wants to show that the structures are different and player $II$ wants to show that they are equal. I will use the standard convention that player $I$ is male and player $II$ is female.
- We say that player $II$ *wins the game in* $G_n(\mathscr M, \mathscr N)$ if the resulting set of pairs $\{(m_i, n_i) \in M \times N : i=1, \dots, n\}$ is the graph of a partial embedding; a *winning strategy for player* $II$ is a sequence of moves that makes player $II$ win the game.
- Since we work over the language $\{<, =\}$, $\{(m_i, n_i) \in M \times N : i=1, \dots, n\}$ is the graph of a partial embedding if $$m_i=m_j \ \ \iff \ \ n_i = n_j$$ and $$m_i < m_j \ \ \iff n_i<n_j$$ for all $i, j = 1, \dots, n$.

The result that we will make use of is the following:

> **Theorem** (Theorem 2.4.6 in Marker's book): Let $\mathscr L$ be a finite language without function symbols and let $\mathscr M$ and $\mathscr N$ be $\mathscr L$-structures. Then $\mathscr M \equiv \mathscr N$ if and only if player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_n(\mathscr M, \mathscr N)$ for all $n$.

---

By the above theorem, $\mathscr A \equiv \mathscr B$ implies that player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$ for all $n$ and similarly for $\mathscr A' \equiv \mathscr B'$; using these assumptions, we show that player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_n(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$ for all $n$ by induction on $n$, and then $\mathscr A + \mathscr A' \equiv  \mathscr B + \mathscr B'$ will follow again by the above theorem.

The idea is as follows. For each $n$, player $I$ and $II$ are playing the "public" game $G_n(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$, but player $II$ is playing simultaneously other two "private" games $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$ and $G_n(\mathscr A', \mathscr B')$. When player $I$ makes a move in the game $G_n(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$ he has to pick an element of one of $A, A', B$ or $B'$, say $a\in A$; before player $II$ makes a move in the game $G_n(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$, she replicates the move of player $I$ in her private game $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$ and then uses the same move that she does in $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$ to make her move in $G_n(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$. Therefore, for each move of player $I$ in the public game, player $II$ replicates the move of player $I$ in the appropiate private game and then uses the same move that she does in this private game to make a move in the public game; note that the private game that player $II$ plays each round of the public game depends on the choice of player $I$, so if player $I$ chooses $b \in B$ then player $II$ plays in the private game $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$, and if player $I$ chooses $a'\in A'$ then player $II$ plays in the private game $G_n(\mathscr A', \mathscr B')$.

With this idea in mind the induction is pretty straightforward. The base case is $n=1$, and here we don't have much to do. Say (without loss of generality) that player $I$ picks $a \in A$; then player $II$ replicates player $I$'s move in her private game $G_n(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$ and by assumption player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_1(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$, so she wins the game $G_1(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$. But this winning strategy also makes player $II$ win the public game, so we're done with the case $n=1$. Being pedantic, we could say that what happens here is that if $\{(a,b)\}$ is the graph of a partial embedding $\mathscr A \rightarrow \mathscr B$ then it is also the graph of a partial embedding $\mathscr A + \mathscr A' \rightarrow \mathscr B + \mathscr B'$.

Assume now as inductive hypothesis that player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_k(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$ for some $k \geq 2$ and consider the game $G_{k+1}(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$; this means that we have a partial embedding given by the graph $$\{(a_i, b_i) \in (A\dot{\cup}A')\times(B\dot{\cup}B') : i= 1, \dots, k\}$$ and we want to extend it to a partial embedding with graph  $$\{(a_i, b_i) \in (A\dot{\cup}A')\times(B\dot{\cup}B') : i= 1, \dots, k+1\}.$$ For the first $k$ rounds of the game $G_{k+1}(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B + \mathscr B')$ let player $II$ play as in the game $G_k(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$ and assume (again without loss of generality) that player $I$ picks $a_{k+1} \in A$ in round $k+1$. Throughout the public game $G_{k+1}(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B + \mathscr B')$ player $II$ has been playing two private games $G_{r_1}(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$  and $G_{r_2}(\mathscr A', \mathscr B')$ of length $0 \leq r_1\leq k+1$ and $0 \leq  r_2 \leq k+1$, respectively; here we have that $k+1 = r_1 +r_2$ and length $r_1=0$ (say) means that all rounds of the private games were carried out in $G_{r_2}(\mathscr A', \mathscr B')$. By assumption, player $II$ has a winning strategy in $G_{r_1}(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$, so she can pick $b_{k+1} \in B$ to win $G_{r_1}(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$; I claim that the sequence of moves of player $II$ in game $G_k(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B+ \mathscr B')$ followed by picking $b_{k+1}$ in round $k+1$ is a winning strategy for player $II$ in the game $G_{k+1}(\mathscr A + \mathscr A', \mathscr B + \mathscr B')$. To show this we just need to prove that $$\{(a_i, b_i) \in (A\dot{\cup}A')\times(B\dot{\cup}B') : i= 1, \dots, k\} \cup \{(a_{k+1}, b_{k+1})\}$$ is a partial embedding, and this in turn amounts to show that $$a_i=a_j \ \ \iff \ \ b_i=b_j$$ and $$a_i<a_j \ \ \iff \ \ b_i <b_j$$ for all $i, j \in \{1, 2, \dots, k+1\}$. Since $$\{(a_i, b_i) \in (A\dot{\cup}A')\times(B\dot{\cup}B') : i= 1, \dots, k\}$$ is already a partial embedding, it suffices to check these three conditions for all $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, k+1\}$:

1. $a_i = a_{k+1}$ if and only if $b_i = b_{k+1}$.
2. $a_i < a_{k+1}$ if and only if $b_i < b_{k+1}$.
3. $a_{k+1} < a_i$ if and only if $b_{k+1} < b_i$.

The first condition is trivial, so we verify the last two. Let $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, k+1\}$. Then:

2. Suppose that $a_i < a_{k+1}$. Then (by definition of the interpretation of $<$ in $\mathscr A + \mathscr A'$) we have that $a_i \in A$ and $a_i < a_{k+1}$ in $\mathscr A$, and since player $II$ wins the game $G_{r_1}(\mathscr A, \mathscr B)$, the resulting set of pairs of this game is the graph of a partial embedding, so $b_i < b_{k+1}$ in $\mathscr B$ and hence $b_i < b_{k+1}$ in $\mathscr B + \mathscr B'$. The converse is exactly analogous.
3. Suppose that $a_{k+1} < a_i$. Then (by definition of the interpretation of $<$ in $\mathscr A + \mathscr A'$) either $a_i \in A$ and $a_{k+1} < a_i$ in $\mathscr A$ or $a_i \in \mathscr A'$. The former case is as the one above, so we consider the case of $a_i \in \mathscr A'$; but this is trivial, since $a_i \in \mathscr A'$ implies $b_i \in \mathscr B'$, and since $b_{k+1} \in \mathscr B$ we have (by definition of the interpretation of $<$ in $\mathscr B + \mathscr B'$) that $b_{k+1} < b_i$ in $\mathscr B + \mathscr B'$.

This shows that $\{(a_i, b_i) \in (A\dot{\cup}A')\times(B\dot{\cup}B') : i= 1, \dots, k\} \cup \{(a_{k+1}, b_{k+1})\}$ is a partial embedding, concluding thus the inductive step; the result hence follows by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, a stronger proposition$^\dagger$ holds: if $A\preceq A'$ and $B\preceq B'$, then $A+B\preceq A'+B'$, even if you add predicates for $A$ and $B$, and even if $A$ and $B$ are only partially ordered.

To show this, notice that $M=(A+B,<,A,B)$ is bidefinable with $M_s=(A\sqcup B,<_A,<_B,A,B)$ (where $<_A,<_B$ are the restrictions of the respective orderings to $A$ and $B$). Now, it is not hard to see that $M_s\preceq N_s=(A'\sqcup B',<_{A'},<_{B'},A',B')$. This follows from the general fact that disjoint union (of arbitrary structures) preserves elementary inclusions.

Now,since $M_s\preceq N_s$, it follows (by bidefinability) that $(A+B,<,A,B)\preceq(A'+B',<,A',B')$, and hence also $(A+B,<)\preceq (A'+B',<)$.

($\dagger$ In case it is not clear why this is stronger, notice that if $A\equiv A'$ and $B\equiv B'$, then there are $A'',B''$ into which $A$, $A'$ and $B,B'$ embed elementarily.)